# Hide/Toggle submenu when clicking on another menu item

Tags: jquery, toggle, hide

This is what I have right now: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rd6bX/)

When you click on Category 1 and then on Category 2, I would like the sub menu of Category 1 to close. How can I achieve that?

All I have achieved right now, is to close the sub menu(s) when clicking anywhere on the screen except on the menu:

```
$(function () {
$('nav ul li').not("nav ul li ul li").click(function(e){
    $(this).children('ul').stop().toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$("nav ul li ul li").click(function(e){
    $(this).children('ul').stop().toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
});
$(document).click(function() {
    $("nav ul li ul").hide();
});
```

Thanks a lot for any responses!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just hide all li's before toggling current li -

```
$('nav ul li').not("nav ul li ul li").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("nav ul li ul").hide();
    $(this).children('ul').stop().toggle();
});
```

Demo `----->` http://jsfiddle.net/rd6bX/17/

Comment: Ah! not quite yet. Now it hides Category 1, when clicking on Category 1.1!

Answer (score 4):

Incase you have multiple levels you could achieve this with just one click handler rather than defining separate handlers for each level:

```
$(function () {
    $('nav > ul > li a').click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
        var $parentli = $(this).closest('li');
        $parentli.siblings('li').find('ul:visible').hide();
        $parentli.find('> ul').stop().toggle();
    });

});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MA4Q6/)

Comment: Yep, great way of doing it!

Answer (score 0):

`$('ul',$(this).siblings()).slideUp();` add this after toggling a ul, to look for ul in all sibling li elements and hide them.

Like this :

```
$(function () {
$('nav ul li').not("nav ul li ul li").click(function(e){
    $(this).children('ul').stop().toggle();
    $('ul',$(this).siblings()).slideUp();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$("nav ul li ul li").click(function(e){
    $(this).children('ul').stop().toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
});
$(document).click(function() {
    $("nav ul li ul").hide();
});
```